# "PATCH DATA RECEIVED" message. For what and from whom?

Tags: windows, notifications

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, 21H2. Just now I got a message I don't understand. It doesn't say who it's from or what it's for.

Here's the popup I saw (sorry about the darkness, I just barely caught it before it disappeared):

[image: Patch notification]

Does anyone have an idea what this might be? I suspect if it was some kind of an attack I wouldn't be notified, but I think any notifications ought to say what they are for.

Comment: That is not a Windows Notification.  It is either some software you have installed, or possibly a virus. Run a full scan with Windows Defender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Images search for this term leads to software called **[0patch](https://0patch.com/patches.html)**, which appears to be a security system which automatically deploys security fixes to applications (much like Windows Update, but for a much broader set of software). There's a [manual](https://0patch.com/files/0patch_Agent_User_Manual_20.06.18.10800.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. I think I installed that last year in response to an unfixed Windows zero-day exploit, and then promptly forgot about it. I would think, though, that the notification could have been a bit clearer.

Comment: @Robusto - It uses the logo of 0patch.  The notification center, if it appeared in the notification center, would have indicated which application was generating the notification.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yeah, about that: No matter what I try, and I've researched and tried everything, I can't get the Notification center to display anymore. That's why I have to catch the popups before they fade, because I'll never be able to see them again.

Comment: Also, the 0patch logo is more arty than informative, IMO.

Comment: @Robusto - You should be able to see a list of notifications that have not been dismissed, provided 0patch even generated a notification, applications can also generate notifications that do not appear in the notification center. Guessing by the design of the notification I would guess the application was generating and display it's own notifications instead of generating a notification that would appear in the notification center.  I have no desire to install 0patch to find out.